# How to set layout when call module in component joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

In a component how to call a module:

```
tmpl
---default.php
---hello.php
mod_hello.php
mod_hello.xml
helper.php    

$module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_hello');
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule ($module );
```

When I `echo` the result using layout `default`, how to show layout of module mod_hello is `hello` layout

Answer (score 0):

Read below forum thread, this might help you out

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=544&t=356176

```
$modules =& JModuleHelper::getModules('mod_hello'); 
foreach ($modules as $module) 
{ 
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module); 
} 


$document = &JFactory::getDocument();
$renderer = $document->loadRenderer('modules');
$options = array('style'=>'raw');
echo $renderer->render('mod_hello',$options,null);
```

There is 2 way to call Module :

Call Module within Content/Article : you can use {loadposition position} (thanks to plgContentLoadModule - /plugins/content/loadmodule.php)

Call Module programatically (Module call another Module or Component call Module) :

```
A. Call Module by position :

$position = 'left';
$contents = '';
foreach (JModuleHelper::getModules($position) as $mod) {
$contents .= $renderer->render($mod, $params);
}

B. Call Module by name :

$modName = 'mostread '; // not mod_mostread 
$modTitle = 'Popular';
$mod = JModuleHelper::getModule($modName, $modTitle);
$content = JModuleHelper::renderModule($mod);
```

Answer (score 0):

How I did it:

There is an $attribs array which is in the module's context so you can use it to pass the layout

```
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_hello');
$attribs = array('layout'=>'hello');
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule ($module,$attribs);
```

And after that in mod_hello.php:

```
$layout = isset($attribs['layout'])?$attribs['layout']:'default';
require(JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_hello',$layout));
```